# Pyspark Dataframe - Median Without Numpy Or Other Libraries

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, median

I've been working on this in pyspark for a while and I'm stuck. I'm trying to get the median of the column **numbers**  for its respective window. I need to do this without the use of other libraries such as numpy etc.

So far (as depicted below), I've grouped the dataset into windows by the column **id**. This is depicted by the column **row_numbers** which shows you what each window looks like. There are three windows in this dataframe example.

**This is what I would like:**

I want each row to also contain the median of the window of the column **id** without taking its own row into consideration. The location of the median I require is in my function below called **median_loc**

Example: For the **row_number** = 5, I need to find the median for the rows 1 to 4 above it (i.e. not including **row_number** 5). The median therefore (per my requirement) is the average of the column **id** in the same window where **row_number** = 1 and **row_number** = 2 i.e

```
Date        id      numbers row_number  med_loc
2017-03-02  group 1   98        1       [1]
2017-04-01  group 1   50        2       [1]
2018-03-02  group 1   5         3       [1, 2]
2016-03-01  group 2   49        1       [1]
2016-12-22  group 2   81        2       [1]
2017-12-31  group 2   91        3       [1, 2]
2018-08-08  group 2   19        4       [2]
2018-09-25  group 2   52        5       [1, 2]
2017-01-01  group 3   75        1       [1]
2018-12-12  group 3   17        2       [1]
```

The code I used to get the last column med_loc is as follow

```
def median_loc(sz):
    if sz == 1 or sz == 0:
        kth = [1]
        return kth
    elif sz % 2 == 0 and sz > 1:
        szh = sz // 2
        kth = [szh - 1, szh] if szh != 1 else [1, 2]
        return kth
    elif sz % 2 != 0 and sz > 1:
        kth = [(sz + 1) // 2]
        return kth


sqlContext.udf.register("median_location", median_loc)

median_loc = F.udf(median_loc)

df = df.withColumn("med_loc", median_loc(df.row_number)-1)
```

*Note : I only made them look like a list for easier understanding. It is just to show where the median is located in the respective window. It is just for the easier understanding of folks reading this on Stack Overflow*

The output that I desire is as follows:

```
Date        id      numbers row_number  med_loc     median
2017-03-02  group 1   98        1       [1]           98
2017-04-01  group 1   50        2       [1]           98
2018-03-02  group 1   5         3       [1, 2]        74
2016-03-01  group 2   49        1       [1]           49
2016-12-22  group 2   81        2       [1]           49
2017-12-31  group 2   91        3       [1, 2]        65
2018-08-08  group 2   19        4       [2]           81
2018-09-25  group 2   52        5       [1, 2]        65
2017-01-01  group 3   75        1       [1]           75
2018-12-12  group 3   17        2       [1]           75
```

Basically, the way to get the median so far is something like this:

1. If med_loc is one digit (i.e if the list has just one digit such [1] or [3] et.) then median = df.numbers where *df.row_number = df.med_loc*
2. If med_loc is two digits (i.e if the list has two digits such as [1,2] or [2, 3] etc.) then median = average(df.numbers) where *df.row_number in df.med_loc*

I cannot stress enough how important it is for me **not** to use other libraries such as numpy etc. to get the output. There are other solutions that I looked at that used np.median and they work, however, that is not my requirement at this time.

I'm sorry if this explanation is so winded and if I'm complicating it. I've been looking at this for days and can't seem to figure it out. I also tried to use the percent_rank function but I'm not able to figure it out because not all windows contain 0.5 percentile.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If I just have the median, that would be great. med_loc is not absolutely necessary.  Spark version is 2.1.1.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. For `group 1` shouldn't the median be the average of the other two rows for all rows? Why is it `98` for row 1 and 2?

Comment: -group 1 - row 1 = 98 because of no other point of reference so it uses itself
 --- 
-group 1 - row 2 = 98 because it does not consider itself now that it has at least some historical reference, so it compares to the data in row 1

Comment: So you want the rolling median for each group, ordered by Date and not including the current row (unless it's the first)?

Comment: Correct. That is what I would ideally like to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you start with the following DataFrame, `df`:

```python
+----------+-------+-------+
|      Date|     id|numbers|
+----------+-------+-------+
|2017-03-02|group 1|     98|
|2017-04-01|group 1|     50|
|2018-03-02|group 1|      5|
|2016-03-01|group 2|     49|
|2016-12-22|group 2|     81|
|2017-12-31|group 2|     91|
|2018-08-08|group 2|     19|
|2018-09-25|group 2|     52|
|2017-01-01|group 3|     75|
|2018-12-12|group 3|     17|
+----------+-------+-------+
```

#### Order DataFrame

First add the `row_number` as you did in your example and assign the output to a new DataFrame `df2`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df2 = df.select(
    "*", f.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("Date")).alias("row_number")
)
df2.show()
#+----------+-------+-------+----------+
#|      Date|     id|numbers|row_number|
#+----------+-------+-------+----------+
#|2017-03-02|group 1|     98|         1|
#|2017-04-01|group 1|     50|         2|
#|2018-03-02|group 1|      5|         3|
#|2016-03-01|group 2|     49|         1|
#|2016-12-22|group 2|     81|         2|
#|2017-12-31|group 2|     91|         3|
#|2018-08-08|group 2|     19|         4|
#|2018-09-25|group 2|     52|         5|
#|2017-01-01|group 3|     75|         1|
#|2018-12-12|group 3|     17|         2|
#+----------+-------+-------+----------+
```

#### Collect Values for Median

Now you can join `df2` to itself on the `id` column with the condition that the left side's `row number` is `1` or it is greater than the right side's `row_number`. Then group by the left DataFrame's `("id", "Date", "row_number")` and collect the `numbers` from the right DataFrame into a list.

For the case when the `row_number` is equal to 1, we only want to keep the first element of this collected list. Otherwise keep all the numbers, but sort them because we need to have them ordered to calculate the median.

Call this intermediate DataFrame `df3`:

```python
df3 = df2.alias("l").join(df2.alias("r"), on="id", how="left")\
    .where("l.row_number = 1 OR (r.row_number < l.row_number)")\
    .groupBy("l.id", "l.Date", "l.row_number")\
    .agg(f.collect_list("r.numbers").alias("numbers"))\
    .select(
        "id",
        "Date",
        "row_number",
        f.when(
            f.col("row_number") == 1,
            f.array([f.col("numbers").getItem(0)])
        ).otherwise(f.sort_array("numbers")).alias("numbers")
    )
df3.show()
#+-------+----------+----------+----------------+
#|     id|      Date|row_number|         numbers|
#+-------+----------+----------+----------------+
#|group 1|2017-03-02|         1|            [98]|
#|group 1|2017-04-01|         2|            [98]|
#|group 1|2018-03-02|         3|        [50, 98]|
#|group 2|2016-03-01|         1|            [49]|
#|group 2|2016-12-22|         2|            [49]|
#|group 2|2017-12-31|         3|        [49, 81]|
#|group 2|2018-08-08|         4|    [49, 81, 91]|
#|group 2|2018-09-25|         5|[19, 49, 81, 91]|
#|group 3|2017-01-01|         1|            [75]|
#|group 3|2018-12-12|         2|            [75]|
#+-------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

Notice that the `numbers` column of `df3` has a list of the appropriate values for which we want to find the median.

#### Compute Median

Since your version of Spark is greater than 2.1, you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode()` to compute the median from this list of values. For lower versions of spark, you would need to use a `udf`.

First create 2 helper columns in `df3`:

- `isEven`: A Boolean to indicate if the `numbers` array has an even number of elements
- `middle`: The index of the middle of the array, which is the floor of the length / 2

After these columns are created, explode the array using `posexplode()`, which will return two new columns: `pos` and `col`. We then filter out the resultant DataFrame to only keep the positions that we need to compute the median.

The logic on which positions to keep is as follows:

- If `isEven` is `False`, we only keep the middle position
- IF `isEven` is `True`, we keep the middle position and the middle position - 1.

Finally group by the `id` and `Date` and average the remaining `numbers`.

```python
df3.select(
    "*",
    f.when(
        (f.size("numbers") % 2) == 0,
        f.lit(True)
    ).otherwise(f.lit(False)).alias("isEven"),
    f.floor(f.size("numbers")/2).alias("middle")
).select(
        "id", 
        "Date",
        "middle",
        f.posexplode("numbers")
).where(
    "(isEven=False AND middle=pos) OR (isEven=True AND pos BETWEEN middle-1 AND middle)"
).groupby("id", "Date").agg(f.avg("col").alias("median")).show()
#+-------+----------+------+
#|     id|      Date|median|
#+-------+----------+------+
#|group 1|2017-03-02|  98.0|
#|group 1|2017-04-01|  98.0|
#|group 1|2018-03-02|  74.0|
#|group 2|2016-03-01|  49.0|
#|group 2|2016-12-22|  49.0|
#|group 2|2017-12-31|  65.0|
#|group 2|2018-08-08|  81.0|
#|group 2|2018-09-25|  65.0|
#|group 3|2017-01-01|  75.0|
#|group 3|2018-12-12|  75.0|
#+-------+----------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I’m not at my computer now but will check over the weekend and upvote if it matches what I’m looking for! Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I had to modify the df2 line because df.select("*", <whatever>) does not seem to work on my machine but I just used the same dataframe that I had used earlier that already had the row numbers.